# Nifi: how to convert multiple log file in one file?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I  have  many internal log ,   which  i  write myself  inside  nifi environment, i want to  input  all  this  data inside  one  log  flowFile,  but  this  code  trows  Null pointer  exception what  should  i change?

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.FlowFileFilter;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;

def flowFile = session.get();
def  n=0;

if(!flowFile)return
def size = flowFile.getAttribute('fileSize');
int value = size as Integer;
log.error("g");
if((value/338)>1){
def ffList = session.get(new FlowFileFilter(){
    public FlowFileFilterResult filter(FlowFile ff) {
    
        if( size == ff.getAttribute('fileSize') ){ n++; return FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE;
        }
        else{
        return FlowFileFilterResult.REJECT_AND_CONTINUE
        }
    }
    
})

session.transfer(ffList[n-1],REL_SUCCESS);
session.remove( ffList[0..-2] )
session.remove(flowFile);

}
else{

session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS);
}
```